# Are there any Difference Restoration between Acronis and Deepfreeze towards an expired trial account?

Tags: acronis-trueimage, deep-freeze

So I was wondering this since there is some talk in forum about the usage of ***Deepfreeze*** as an undo trick for an expired trial account (reference link: https://soehoe.id/how-to-use-tick-data-suite.t11569/ --> some talk about bypass expiracy of some software called TDS (Tick Data Suite).

But since ***Deepfreeze*** is mainly a Backup & Restore software, I wonder are its execution difference compared to ***Acronis***? (I only use ***Acronis*** to do Backup, while I still kinda didn't experience yet either the restoration by ***Acronis*** and ***Deepfreeze***) Since Acronis way of restoration is to make replicate a complete image of a System as stated by its owner, so by my point of view it should also can affect the undo of an expired trial account, or am I wrong? Appreciate if theres any expert who know about this. Thank you

Comment: Deepfreeze is not a backup solution.

Comment: @Ramhound oh okay, so its actually only for restoration purpose..?

Comment: It's to preserve a fixed state. All 'new' data is discarded every boot time, so the machine never changes. Resetting trial accounts depends on the method to recognise the trial end. Trials have got more & more clever over the years - precisely to prevent people doing that.